# Error in sharing sharing html content between two domains

Tags: django, angularjs, cors, django-cors-headers

I have one Django web service application running in domain A. The application uses a content file for storing some HTML files and images needed it. Another application running on domain B want to access my services and content. I enabled  CORS in my domain A. Now I can access  web services running on domain A from domain B and also the image files from domain A. But I have some HTML in the content file. I can't access that HTML content from domain B.

Domain B implemented using angularjs which useses `ng-include` to render my HTML page. CORS also enabled in domain B.

Application *settings.py* domain A

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'corsheaders',
)

# CORS HEADERS settings
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True  # Default False
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
'GET',
'POST',
'PUT',
'PATCH',
'DELETE',
'OPTIONS'
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
'x-requested-with',
'content-type',
'accept',
'origin',
'authorization'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your response headers and make sure they are carrying the all the proper `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers. CORS requests require preflight success.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103876/cors-cookie-credentials-from-mobile-webview-loaded-locally-with-file/23051298#23051298) for more information.