# Cross domain issue, GET converted to OPTIONS

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile, cors

I have the following request and response. The Access allow control origin is set to *.

```
Remote Address:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx
Request URL:http://api-test.example.com/api/v1/sample
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api-test.example.com
Origin:http://test.example.com
Referer:http://test.example.com/Joblist.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like GeChrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
```

Response:

```
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http:*
Allow:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:76
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 15 Apr 2014 07:38:32 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I have used the GET method, but it is getting converted to OPTIONS, How to fix this?

Here is the calling function:

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "GET", 
url: "api-test.example.com/api/v1/sample";, 
headers:{Authorization:authHeader}, 
dataType: "xml", 
success: function(xml) {
```

Comment: "I have used the GET method" show it then

Comment: $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://api-test.example.com/api/v1/sample",
   headers:{Authorization:authHeader},
   dataType: "xml", 
   success: function(xml)
   {

Comment: This should help you [jQuery CORS Content-type OPTIONS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320467/jquery-cors-content-type-options)

Comment: @user3393032 url: "api-test.example.com/api/v1/sample"`;`,   you have a ; here. dont know if related to problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103876/cors-cookie-credentials-from-mobile-webview-loaded-locally-with-file/23051298#23051298)...

The browser will prefly an `OPTIONS` request any time there are not-simple headers in a cross origin request. When this `OPTIONS` request is sent to the server, the server must respond with allowable headers, methods, AND origins to satisfy the preflight request (and allow the actual request to be made).

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http:*
```

`http:*` is not going to qualify as an allowed origin. It only supports *, null or the exact domain.

[here is some info](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header)