# Is it Angular $http.defaults.useXDomain really neccessary in CORS?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors

I saw someone using $http.defaults.useXDomain = true in angular when dealing with CORS. Is it really necessary to do that?

I just set up laravel and angular in different domain ( By different domain, I mean I put angular and laravel in completely separated folder in localhost www folder. FYI i use nginx). i hit the laravel controller with http request from angular. It just work fine, Whether i use the $http.defaults.useXDomain or not.

Luckily, this condition make my work little bit easier. but i still wondering is there any explanation why this happened?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2956

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. In fact, it's not a thing.

[check it out](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/angular/kl2BVOubG4I)

Cors works via proper headers/preflight requests and responses, which you can do myriad of different ways in angularjs.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103876/cors-cookie-credentials-from-mobile-webview-loaded-locally-with-file/23051298#23051298) is more about cors workings.