# Unable to bypass CORS in angularjs seed app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, marklogic

I'm using [angularjs-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) app and I'm trying to get JSON response from server (MarkLogic) using `$http`. I've been on it for 3 days tried every response from other similar stackoverflow answers but not able to get it working. Please help!

The browser returns this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sreddy:8003/v1/search?format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here's my app code

**app.js**

```
'use strict';


// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'});
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html', controller: 'MyCtrl2'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});

  // to avoid CORS
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);


app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, dataService) {
      $scope.test = "test";
      $scope.data = null;
      dataService.getData().then(function (dataResponse) {
          $scope.data = dataResponse;
      });
      console.log($scope.data);
  }]);

  app.controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {
      console.log("from MyCtrl2");
  }]);
```

**services.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Services */


// Demonstrate how to register services
// In this case it is a simple value service.
var app = angular.module('myApp.services', []);

app.value('version', '0.1');

app.service('dataService', function($http) {

this.getData = function() {
    // $http() returns a $promise that we can add handlers with .then()
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://sreddy:8003/v1/search?format=json'
     });
 }
});
```

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` means that it is expecting a header from the server.  Have you added this header to the server response?  You cannot solve this with client side only changes.

Comment: Ah! I thought it can be handled on client side alone. Let me try again(the right way) & get back to you. Thank you sir!

Comment: Added headers in server response code and got it working. Thank you Davin.

Comment: This is purely a server-side config, since Angular already sends Origin header by default.

Comment: @Sudhakar What headers did you add? And how did you add them? Thank you.

Comment: I modified the server source code:
`return
    if (exists($response)) 
then(eput:add-response-header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", xdmp:get-request-header('Origin')),    
      eput:add-response-header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true"), 
    $response)`

I've mentioned the The same info in my github project readme as well https://github.com/csreddy/angularjs-oscars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useXDomain` is not a thing.

You are indeed having a same-origin problem. In order for your request to work, you will need to change your headers on the request. Since you are making a simple `GET` request, you should be able to do it, provided it's a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests). Your content-type is likely what is flagging the request as a CORS request.

Usually - this can be fixed by setting your `content-type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`, like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://sreddy:8003/v1/search?format=json',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'text/plain'} //or whatever type
 });
```

Or - you can set up an interceptor and add headers to all requests meeting some criteria.

For not-simple requests, which may get [preflighted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests), you will need to work more with the request headers in addition to ensure response headers satisfy the preflight request. If you don't have access to the server (to set response headers), you will have to work within their allowed parameters. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103876/cors-cookie-credentials-from-mobile-webview-loaded-locally-with-file/23051298#23051298) is some more info on CORS.

Comment: I was following instructions given here http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/. Anyway its working for me now. Thank you for your response. appreciate it!

Comment: It's all good. Many people have seen that blog (and others like it), promulgating this non-existent `useXDomain` feature, which actually was never in AngularJs. [Check it out](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2956#issuecomment-19493940)

Comment: @Sudhakar please consider accepting the answer (and possibly upvoting it) if it helped solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run an http server - simplest way is using python

from the main directory of the project...

```
python3 -m http.server 8080
```

Then go to the url `localhost:8080/index.html` and you'r golden !

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. I must change server side response header for it to work

Comment: I used PHP built-in server! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issues by using express.js as a proxy server which also enables me to serve static content usinf the proxy