# Calling MVC API within AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, angular-services

UPDATE:
here is the error i am getting when i do `console.log`  right before the line $scope.Host = data;

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://..... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:52029' is therefore not allowed access.`

I'm trying to call an API that returns JSON data, I'm beginner in AngularJS and what I'm trying to do is to call an API and display the data very simply.

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <script src="../scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-app="MyModule">

        <table class="table" data-ng-controller="MyModuleCtrl">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    FirstName
                </th>
                <th>
                    MiddleName
                </th>
                <th>
                    LastName
                </th>
                <th>
                    Email
                </th>
                <th>
                    Active
                </th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{Host.FirstName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Host.MiddleName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Host.LastName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Host.Email}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Host.Active}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="../scripts/MyApp/App.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The App.js file:

```
var MyModule = angular.module("MyModule", []);

MyModule.factory('MyHttpService',
    ['$http', function ($http) {

    return {
        getAll: function () {
            return $http.get('http://api.host.com/host'); //it returns json data
        }
 };
}]);

MyModule.controller('MyModuleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', 'MyHttpService', 
    function ($scope, $http, $window, MyHttpService) {

        load();

        function load() {
            MyHttpService.getAll().success(function (data) {
               $scope.Host = data;
            }
        );
    }
}]);
```

Comment: And what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: because that code works... http://plnkr.co/edit/1xaoZbSeY37wJpJYOi0C

Comment: Have you verified your web api via browser/postman/fiddler?

Comment: the problem is that it not getting data and yes i verified in the browser and it does spit json data.

Comment: @Brocco: i see that its working and your `json` file is within the folder and when i replace your `host.json` file to the `api url` then it does not display any data.

Comment: Right before the line `$scope.Host = data;` put `console.log(data);` then check the browser's console and post the results.

Comment: i updated my question and i see that i am getting error

Comment: `$http.get('http://api.host.com/host');` is why you are getting a CORS/xhr exception. Because that domain is different than that of your angular app, your browser is treating it as a CORS request. You have 2 choices- handle the CORS request on your server, or set the domains the same and remove the CORS problem. If you choose option 1, look at setting CORS response headers that allow your request. If you choose option 2 (make requests to localhost:<urPort>), the code you have should work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of offering an answer:

`$http.get('http://api.host.com/host');` is why you are getting a CORS/xhr exception. Because that domain is different than that of your angular app, your browser is treating it as a CORS request. You have 2 choices- handle the CORS request on your server, or set the domains the same and remove the CORS problem. If you choose option 1, look at setting CORS response headers that allow your request. If you choose option 2 (make requests to localhost:<urPort>), the code you have should work correctly.

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103876/cors-cookie-credentials-from-mobile-webview-loaded-locally-with-file/23051298#23051298) where I went into more detail about how CORS works/how the browser handles a CORS request.