# How to get data from mediawiki api using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, api, mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia

While I try to access wiki api using Angularjs $http.get(), CORS issues occured. Here is my code

$http.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=India')
                .success(function(data){
                    console.log('data' +data);
                });

And this is the error message

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&exintro=&titles=India. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Refer this one.... it is because of CORS ....   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use JSONP](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests) for cross-site requests.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following SO answer regarding CORS:

[CORS, Cordova, AngularJs $http and file:// confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914071/cors-cordova-angularjs-http-and-file-confusion/25914800#25914800)

As well as the mentioned in the comment:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 0):

See [Manual:CORS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CORS) and [API:Cross-site requests](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Cross-site_requests). Specifically, you need to set [`$wgCrossSiteAJAXdomains`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCrossSiteAJAXdomains) and add an `origin` parameter to your request.