# What should be allowed origin for AWS CORS for Cordova app

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, cors

As per all the tutorials, to enable CORS on AWS S3 bucket, following configuration should be done. I have done this and it works for cordova app and works fine. Here, we are allowing - origin as - * which enables all the sites. How can I restrict it to only my cordova app developed in html5 for android/ ios.
What should be the value in AllowedOrigin tag for cordova app to allow only my app to access the bucket.

```
<CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the origins that you want to allow cross-domain requests from, for example, http://www.example.com. The origin string can contain at most one * wildcard character.You can also specify https://*.example.com to enable only secure origins.

Comment: For website, it is quite straight forward, as you have suggested. I want to know  for cordova app (Android or iOS) installed on the mobile.What is url for such installed apps ?

Comment: Please were you able to solve this? I am also having similar problem

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this topic.
Basically CORS does not apply to file:// sources which is what cordova uses.

[CORS, Cordova, AngularJs $http and file:// confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914071/cors-cordova-angularjs-http-and-file-confusion?rq=1)