# Client side(Jquery&Angular) can't send request with x-access-token headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, express

I followed [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) build a web api with token in Node.js:

```
var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
```

`if (token) {console.log("passed!");}
else
{console.log("No token provided.");}`

I tested with Postman and tried with http://localhost:3000?token=eyJ0eXAiO
all work fine, but when call API in client side:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cookies) {
var apikey=$cookies.get('apikey');
$http({url: 'http://localhost:3000/', method: 'GET', headers: {'x-access-token': apikey}})
```

`.success(function (data) {
  console.log(data); 
}).error(function(error){console.log(error);});`

and jquery call:

```
jQuery.ajax( {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'x-access-token', 'eyJ0eXAi');

    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error : function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
} );
```

What every Angular or jquery did not work and return "No token provided."

what did I miss? Please help me.

Here is headers from req.headers
Angular.JS

> { host: 'localhost:3000',
>     connection: 'keep-alive',
>     'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
>     'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
>     origin: 'localhost:3001',
>     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36',
>     'access-control-request-headers': 'accept, max-age, x-access-token',
>     accept: '*/*',
>     referer: 'localhost:3001',
>     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
>     'accept-language': 'en-CA,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.2,zh-TW;q=0.
>   2' }
>   No token provided.

Postman

> { host: 'localhost:3000',
>     connection: 'keep-alive',
>     csp: 'active',
>     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
>     'x-access-token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoibGF3cmVuY2
>   UiLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6InNreTIwMDAiLCJhZG1pbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaWF0IjoxNDM2Mzc0NTYzLCJleHAiOj
>   E0MzY0NjA5NjN9.OycP6xdUlG3vLyZHcj4rLjyYKE1GnlWc3h-f0r1ZpZ0',
>     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36',
>     'postman-token': 'ab2a26e3-f6a1-09e0-c21a-85e3cef0aff5',
>     accept: '*/*',
>     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
>     'accept-language': 'en-CA,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.2,zh-TW;q=0.
>   2' }
>   passed!

Comment: `console.log(req.headers)`, and inspect with your browser tools whether or not they're being sent in the first place.

Comment: x-access-token not in the headers

Comment: on the server side in node.js code.

Comment: Check it clientside then.

Comment: put the result at bottom of question.

Comment: I think that's client site req:$http({url: 'http://localhost:3000/', method: 'GET', headers: {'x-access-token': apikey,'max-age':1440}})

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this is a Chrome issue, have to run Chrome with --disable-web-security then the headers request works.

[CORS, Cordova, AngularJs $http and file:// confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914071/cors-cordova-angularjs-http-and-file-confusion)