# Cross origin request error in cordova while using ng-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, cross-domain, angular-routing

I have a angular(v1.3.6) application running on cordova. I want to use ng-route(v1.3.6) but while setting up the route-provider, i take surprisingly the following error:

[image]

Here you see my application configuration:

```
puntenApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
            .when('/pb', {
                templateUrl : 'js/pages/pb.html',
                controller  : 'pbController'
            })
            .when('/login', {
                templateUrl : 'js/pages/Login.html',
                controller  : 'configuratieController'
            });
});
```

I have no idea why it is interpreted as a cross origin request (even if i take the html files in the same folder) and what should i do?

Comment: how do you run your code, from a server or from `file://` ?

Comment: from the file where i created my cordova application.

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914071/cors-cordova-angularjs-http-and-file-confusion

Comment: Yes, I'm reading that too but normally, i shouldn't get this kind of error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105910/angular-ng-view-routing-not-working-in-phonegap The current state of my app is less or more the same with it. And i didn't read that anyone using ng-route gets such an error

Answer (score 0):

You have erros in your javascript. You chain function `when` of `$routeProvider` so you have to remove the extra `;`.

So your code should be

```
puntenApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/pb', {
            templateUrl : 'js/pages/pb.html',
            controller  : 'pbController'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl : 'js/pages/Login.html',
            controller  : 'configuratieController'
        });
});
```

Comment: my fault, i made that mistake while i'm writing the code here. It was already without extra `;` so, itm still getting the same error. I've updated my question

Comment: i don't know if it is a typo error, but you have an extra `;` in `$routeProvider` too.