# Ionic app works on Android but not IOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've been building an Ionic app (my first one) and for the life of me I can't figure out why it works on android but not iOS. I'm able to build both with no errors. The app works just as it should in android 6.0.1 but it doesn't work in any version of iOS.

The iOS version of the app loads, but none of the views show up. 
[image]

The Android version: 
[image]

**Here are some details:**
- Cordova 6.0.0
- Ionic 1.7.14
- Android 6.0.1
- iOS isn't working in any version of iOS and the results are the same in the simulator as well as on device.
- XCode doesn't have any errors when compiling but lots of warnings (I think that has to do with the Cordova components.)
- Cordova Installed platforms: android 5.1.0, ios 4.0.1

Again the app runs perfectly on android. The iOS version opens but none of my views show up. The app framework seems to work (like the menu button, etc). I suspect a iOS angular compile issue but I'm not sure what to do.

**Update 1**
After following the suggestion below I enabled debugging in Safari and now I get the following:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E3199C94-4C7E-426C-940D-94A1357A8CDE/SKOApp.app/www/feeds-categories.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

What's particularly interesting is, I don't get a similar CORS error on my local machine nor in android.

Comment: You could take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914071/cors-cordova-angularjs-http-and-file-confusion), which seems to fit your issue

Answer (score 1):

If you have node set up. You can try using http-server.

`npm install http-server -g`

FYI: https://github.com/indexzero/http-server

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**THIS**](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) regarding CORS error with Ionic.

Comment: link is broken :(

Comment: Try now, I fixed the link.