# IONIC/angular is sending origin as file:// in POST and PUT -Getting 403 forbidden Error from API

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on IONIC 3/Angular android app. ionic is sending http header origin as file:// for POST and PUT methods of Http calls. It does not add origin to GET method.

The lib i used is '@angular/http'.

We have strict restrictions on the API side. we cannot modify that.

Can any one suggest a solution?

Following is the snippet of http header

```
    content-type:application/json
    Host:XXXXXXX
    Origin:file://
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Android SDK built 
    for x86 Build/NYC; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
    Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
    X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:XXXXX
    X-Requested-With:com.X.X.X
```

I also looked the following POSTs and forums. No luck

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-app-is-sending-header-origin-file-which-causes-problems/62388

SO link but no solution.

[Ionic native app is sending header Origin:file:// which causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324750/ionic-native-app-is-sending-header-originfile-which-causes-problems)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would solve your problem, but I remember running into this issue when I was making an ionic app awhile back. Looking at how I have my app set up, it looks like I used a proxy to make my http calls on my local. I have a file in the root directory called `ionic.config.json` which is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "mobile",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://your-local-api-address"
    }
  ]
}
```

and then in the file I use to store API info, I have my URL just set to "/api". There definitely is a solution, but it might be that you're trying to do something ionic can't (easily?) do.. like running your live reload while you're trying to run the app on a native device.

***UPDATE***

Basically what I wrote above, but found this older posted from a guy who says he has a workaround, here's his input

> I managed to find a working solution !
>   You need to proxy your api server into livereload so that your web app will 
>   think the api server is actually the same as your livereload server.
>   Proxy configuration specs are here : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-
>   cli#advanced-serve-options
>   For example, if your api server is on 192.168.0.1:8888, you need to add this 
>   to your ionic.project :
>
> ```
> "proxies": [
> {
>   "path": "/api",
>   "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.0.1:8888/api"
> }
> ]
> ```
>
> And then, inside your app, you have to make your api calls like if it was 
>      local, directly from /api.

Here is the link to the older thread

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/89

Comment: Thanks Jake. I think ionic native http might solve the problem. I tried it but got different other error (related to my eco systems) and I am inclined to add file:// in the origin whitelist of my webserver

Comment: something about this just bothers me, lol. I did more looking and found this... it's basically what I'd said but maybe a bit clearer?? I'm going to edit my answer with this additional input, maybe it will help, it's an old post but worth a shot.. otherwise I guess your solution will work