# Refused to display a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, iframe, cors

I am trying to set a iframe in the ionic3 but I am facing with this problem Refused to display a frame of webpages.

This is my code.

```
 <ion-content>
      <div #frame style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll !important;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important">
        <iframe [src]="url" class="iframe" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
      </div>
    </ion-content>

 onInput() {
    this.open = true;
    this.url = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/results?search_query=' + this.myInput);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send a request like *GET*, *POST*, *iframe (GET)*, etc. Your browser or WebView adds by deffault a header in "Request-Headers" with name `"origin"`. That header, **CAN´T** be change it.

In your case, I can see than the url you are trying to embed it´s: `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/results?search_query= + this.myInput"` but Youtube´s documentation say than the url must be: `"http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?origin=http://yourPage.com"`.

When you use `<iframe>` with Youtube, ALWAYS you have to send a origin in parameters of the link.

> **origin:**
>   This parameter provides an extra security measure for the IFrame API
>   and is only supported for IFrame embeds. If you are using the IFrame
>   API, which means you are setting the enablejsapi parameter value to 1,
>   you should always specify your domain as the origin parameter value.
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en-419#origin

Here you have a link to documentation de Youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en-419

Greetings!

Comment: Thank you, but how it is possible to put google.com in the iframe ?

Comment: What? Do you want to put http://google.com inside of a iframe?
You have to put <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?origin=http://yourPage.com" ></iframe>

Comment: I want a input search that there when I type a name and click enter to search in google but this search to show me in iframe, it is that possible

Comment: I don´t know if Youtube has that functionality. I don´t think so. And remember than the search´s url it´s different than watch url and different than embed´s url.
Meaby your best option its use the Youtube API for that.
Here the link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#search_by_keyword

Comment: Thank you I have found some changes, but thank you for the time and for the answers you gave.

Comment: Your welcome. Thanks to you! I learned too many things with this questions and Answers : )

Comment: Yeah I am new in the angular and the Ionic and I want to learn new things.

Comment: I don't find this solution to be true.  I have an iFrame in my app...on Android the url call in the iFrame sends `origin` in the header, but in iOS it does not.  Does anyone know how to force it to send the `origin`....or `referer` or `x-requested-with`.  All are absent from an iOS iframe url call.

Answer (score 1):

Try throwing this in your config.xml file in both platform sections

```
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*youtube.com/*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Youtube set `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` to `SAMEORIGIN` on their response header, so that means only sites with the same origin as Youtube (youtube.com) can load that site in an iframe or object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

You'll have to go about embedding the video the way Youtube wants you to.

Comment: Can you write some code how to do this because I am confused.