# How to remove the Origin header from Cordova rest calls?

Tags: cordova, cross-domain

Cordova app sends `file://` as Origin header.

Of course, since the app is being loaded from the filesystem, this behavior is not too surprising.

However, our backend correctly refuses this origin. See for example: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5193

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25914800/430128) suggests that Cordova apps should not be sending the `file://` `Origin` header, which would work correctly:

> Cross-domain policy does not apply to PhoneGap (for a variety of reasons, basically because your app is essentially running off the file:// URI on-device).

We are using the whitelist plugin, but that does not prevent the `Origin: file://` header from being sent to the server.

It would be ideal for us if Cordova just didn't send the `Origin` header at all. Can it be configured this way?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not too late, you could always switch to https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.

Comment: Did you found a solution?