# Simple angularJS GET function with localhost not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, spring-4

I have a very simple Spring Rest backend that returns JSON data.  The restful URL is working in my browser like this:

`http://localhost:8080/abc/runlist`

It returns data like so:

```
[
  {"stock_num":"KOH19","damage":"Toronto (Oshawa)"},
  {"stock_num":"AZ235","damage":"Toronto (Oshawa)"},
   ...
]
```

I have an independent html page that is not part of my web app.  I just want to test to see if my angular code is getting the data and then looping through it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in names">
        {{ x }}
      </li>
    </ul>

    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/abc/runlist")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
    });
    </script>

    yo yo

    </body>
</html>
```

Why is it not working?  I came across something in Spring where you need to implement something called CORS.  I did that like so but still nothing returned:

```cs
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain  
    chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, 
    DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you tried to use $resource instead of $http? If you console.log(response) is there anything in it?

Comment: You should get data just by navigating to `http://localhost:8080/abc/runlist` with your browser. If data is returned, it's your front-end, otherwise backend. Which is it?

Comment: I get data in my browser.  It's the front end that's the issue.  I also tried $resource.  it doesn't interpret that angular brackets, just prints it out verbatum: {{ x.stock_num }}
yo yo

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:8080/abc/runlist")
           .success(function (response){
              $scope.names = records;
           });
});
```

html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in records">
    {{x}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

more params html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in records">
    {{x.myName}}
    {{x.myNumber}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope I've been helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting return in front of your $http.get

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/abc/runlist").success(function (response) {
        $scope.names = response;
    });
});
</script>
```

then in your view use the dot notation to refer to the properties you want to display e.g.

```
{{x.stock_num}}
```

Comment: Tried that, nothing returned.  Not getting any errors either. :(

Comment: are you able to console.log the data in your success callback?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  There were 2 fixes:

Firstly I had to implement the CORS filter and class in order not get this error:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406)
```

Secondly, a warning for example copiers!  I had copied the simple example above from W3Schools, a great tutorial site as such:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/abc/runlist")
.success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
```

Note the .records at the end of response.  This was not needed.  When I took it off, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely it's being caused by your use of the `file://` scheme. See the middle bullet on the linked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138057/cross-origin-resource-sharing-and-file) for reasoning. Basically your origin is going to be null for `file://` requests, which causes `XmlHttpRequest` to fail, which `$http` relies on.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:8080/abc/runlist")
.success(function (response, data, headers, status, config) {
  $scope.names = response.names;
});
```

hope it will work. :)